# Wide character and character in assignment and equality operators

Tags: c++, char, widechar

Suppose that `wc` is a `wchar_t` and `c` is a `char`.
1) Is there any different between these two assignments?

```
c = 'a';
wc = L'a';
```

2) Is there any rule that force equality of `c` and `wc` for ASCII values? What does exactly mean `wc == c` to compiler?

Comment: Both `char` and `wchar_t` are integral types. The usual integral promotion rules apply.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you. what about that 'L'? If they are two integral, then `'a'` make no difference with `L'a'`. Is it true too?

Comment: @KerrekSB Is it promotion or conversion here? (I'd say it's conversion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- the standard guarantees that both the basic execution character set and the basic wide execution character set will contain 'a', but does not guarantee that it will have the same value in both.

§2.3/3 gives a few restrictions (e.g., digits shall be consecutive), none of which applies here, and a final: "The values of the members of the execution character sets and the sets of additional members are locale-specific."

So, not only is it not guaranteed, but at least in theory it could even change when/if you change the locale.

Comment: What about Kerrek's comment? So being integral both of them, doesn't result to an answer to this question?

Comment: @JalalJaberi: That affects only the types, not the values. You can compare them, but no guarantee is given about the result.

Comment: And comparing them does compare their integral values and then, there is not any guarantee so! Thank you. `char` and `wchar_t` haven't so friendly relationship! :)

Comment: @JalalJaberi: I suppose that's to allow (for example) EBCDIC as the basic execution character set, and Unicode/ISO 10646 as the wide character set. In typical use, you're unlikely to encounter a difference (EBCDIC is virtually the only character set in use that doesn't include most of ASCII as a subset).